# html input field value setter not working properly in chrome and safari using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome

I am trying to set html input field value on keyup event using jquery.

```
<input style="width: 45%;" type="text" name="user_phone" value="" placeholder="Your phone number" />
```

First I tried using .val() setter like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/6xwzy81k/3/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[name=user_phone]').keyup(function() {
    var number = $('input[name=user_phone]').val();
    if (!number.contains('(') && !number.contains(')') && number.length === 2) {            
        $('input[name=user_phone]').val('(' + number + ')');
    } else if (number.contains('(') && !number.contains(')') && number.length === 3) {
        $(this).val(number + ')');
    } else if (!number.contains('(') && number.contains(')') && number.length === 3) {
        $(this).val('(' + number);
    }
  });
});
```

**This worked fine in firefox** but in chrome and safari it didn't work. Then as suggested in some other questions I tried it this way using .prop() instead of .val()

http://jsfiddle.net/6xwzy81k/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[name=user_phone]').keyup(function() {
    var number = $('input[name=user_phone]').val();
    if (!number.contains('(') && !number.contains(')') && number.length === 2) {            
        $('input[name=user_phone]').prop('value','(' + number + ')');
    } else if (number.contains('(') && !number.contains(')') && number.length === 3) {
        $(this).prop('value', number + ')');
    } else if (!number.contains('(') && number.contains(')') && number.length === 3) {
        $(this).prop('value', '(' + number);
    }
  });
});
```

The same thing happened, **it worked as expected in firefox** but not in safari or chrome.

Comment: I don't think `contains()` would work. use `indexOf()`

Comment: ok let me try that, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Accordings to [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#String.prototype.contains): `String.prototype.contains()` was renamed to `String.prototype.includes()` . Moreover: _This is an experimental technology, part of the ECMAScript 6 (Harmony) proposal.
Because this technology's specification has not stabilized, check the compatibility table for usage in various browsers._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was giving `number.contains` is not a function in console. So I suggest you to use `$.contains` as below which works well and good!!

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/6xwzy81k/4/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name=user_phone]').keyup(function() {
        var number = $('input[name=user_phone]').val();
        if (!$.contains(number,'(') && !$.contains(number,')') && number.length === 2) {            
            $('input[name=user_phone]').val('(' + number + ')');
        } else if ($.contains(number,'(') && !$.contains(number,')') && number.length === 3) {
            $(this).val(number + ')');
        } else if (!$.contains(number,'(') && $.contains(number,')') && number.length === 3) {
            $(this).val('(' + number);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your solution works too, but there was a small problem, I shouldn't be able to clear the last ')'. But that was not the main problem, so I'm going to accept it as answer, but implementing the code using .indexOf() instead of .contains() which is working fine the way I want and as it seems like many people recommend not using this one. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

since the error in your code was pointed out by the other answer here is an alternate solution. if you want to format the number in the form (###) ###-#### here is a solution that uses regex to first stip non-digits, then depending on the length of the actual digits, format them. tested in chrome and safari. also handles deletes/backspace

also used your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6xwzy81k/8/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $('input[name=user_phone]').keyup(function() {
        var number = $('input[name=user_phone]').val();
        var digits = number.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, '');
        var lastDigitIndex = (digits.length < 10) ? digits.length : 10;
        
        var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode; 
        
        if (key != 8 && key != 46) {
            if (digits.length >= 3) {
    
                var output = '(' + digits.substring(0, 3) + ') ';
                
                if (digits.length >= 6) {
                    output += digits.substring(3, 6) 
                        + '-' + digits.substring(6, lastDigitIndex);
                }
                else {
                    output += digits.substring(3, lastDigitIndex);
                }
                
                $(this).val(output);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input style="width: 45%;" type="text" name="user_phone" value="" placeholder="Your phone number" />
```

Comment: This one looks great. For now I just have to implement it in simple way, but I guess sooner or later I have to implement something like this. +1